# Smallest Values Which Satisfy Equation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sn = (n+1)/(n+2)

Find the smallest value of M such that 
$|an−1|≤0.001$ for n ≥ M

What I've tried:

$|an| ≤ 1.001$

$(n+1)/(n+2) ≤ 1.001$

$n ≤1.001n + 1.001$

$M ≤0.001n + 1.001$

if n = 1

$M ≤1.002$

I am confused by M as it is not found in the original equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
   |S_n - 1| &\le 0.001 \\
   \left| \dfrac{n+1}{n+2} - 1 \right| &\le 0.001 \\
   \left| \dfrac{-1}{n+2} \right| &\le 0.001 \\
   \dfrac{1}{n+2} &\le \dfrac{1}{1000} \\
   n+2 &\ge 1000 \\
   n \ge 998
\end{align}